# Service not showing in ServiceController but showing in Services and Registry table

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to get the status of NetTcpActivator and NetPipeActivator services in C#.

I used this code to list all the services with a ServiceController:

```
  ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

     foreach (ServiceController service in services)
     {
        string name = service.ServiceName;
        string status = service.Status.ToString();

     }
```

I went in debug but I never see the two services.

If I go in my Services in Windows, I do see the two services.
If I go in the Registry and look for SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services, I do see NetTcpActivator and NetTcpPortSharing. But in the registry, I cannot see the state of the services.

Any idea why I don't see the services with the ServiceController?
Any idea how else to get the service status if it wont show in the ServiceController?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you were iterating through all of the services for debugging purposes, but you could use a simple LINQ statement to get the services you need.

I was able to do these and get the services:

```
var netTcpActivatorService = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == "NetTcpActivator");

var netPipeActivatorService = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == "NetPipeActivator");
```

Comment: Yes, It was only for debug purposes. But the services don't show.

Comment: Thanks, this way it works! I don't know why it didn't the other way. :-)

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey It's quite possible it could have been a case sensitive issue as well? Glad it worked out!